# Group Product Types

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields and I am attempting to group together the custom post types with a similar value from a dropdown field.  As an example. Other would-be its own heading and projectors would have 1 heading with two items.

Here is how I have set up ACF
[image]

Here is my output
[image]

Here is the code I have so far.

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Products By Brand
Template Post Type: Brand
*/

get_header();


//new 

// args - get all the brands, filtered by audience
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
  'post_type'   => array('brand', 'products'),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$counter=0;
$total_posts = $loop->post_count;
$column_divide = 4;


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<div class="fl-content-full container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="fl-content col-md-12">
        <div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none">
        <div class="fl-row-content-wrap">
        <div class="fl-row-content fl-row-fixed-width">


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'medium' ); ?>
        <p>product summary <?php the_field('product_summary'); ?></p>
        <p>manufacture website <?php the_field('website_url_en'); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <?php
    if( $the_query->have_posts()):
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); $counter++;

    $brand_association = get_field('brand_association');
    $product_type = get_field('product_type');
    if( $brand_association ):
    ?>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2><?php the_field('product_type') ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p><img src="<?php the_field('product_image') ?>"/></p>
        <p><?php the_field('product_details') ?></p>
        <p><a href="<?php the_field('hyperlink_to_product_page') ?>">Product Web Page</a></p>
        <p><a href="<?php the_field('hyperlink_to_specifications') ?>">Product Sepcifications</a></p>   
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    
<?php
  if($counter % $column_divide == 0) echo '<div class="row">';
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>

</div><!-- END .col-lg-12-->

            </div><!-- END .row -->
        </div>
        </div><!-- END .fl-content .col-lg-12-->
    </div><!-- END .row -->
</div><!-- END .fl-content-full .container -->


        <h1>hero banner - using beaver themer</h1>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to WPSE, I've read your question but realised you never actually stated the question or problem you're asking about. Note that ACF and other 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic so if your question requires ACF knowledge to answer then the question should be closed as off topic and you'll need to ask in an ACF community or via their support routes

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer for anyone else that may come across this.

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Products By Brand
Template Post Type: Brand
*/

get_header();



// get all of the custom taxonomy terms
$taxonomy = 'product_type';
$arg_terms = array(
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $arg_terms);
$counter=0;
$column_divide = 4;


?>

    <div class="fl-content-full container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="fl-content col-md-12">
        <div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none">
        <div class="fl-row-content-wrap">
        <div class="fl-row-content fl-row-fixed-width">


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'medium' ); ?>
        <p>product summary <?php the_field('product_summary'); ?></p>
        <p>manufacture website <?php the_field('website_url_en'); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">

<?php

// if there are some taxonomy terms, loop through each one and get the posts in that term
if($taxonomy_terms) {
    foreach($taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term) {

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => array('brand','products'),
            "$taxonomy" => $taxonomy_term->slug,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>


<?php       
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>


            <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2><?php echo $taxonomy_term->name; ?></h2>
    </div>


            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); $counter++;

            $brand_association = get_field('brand_association');
        if( $brand_association ):

        ?>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p><img src="<?php the_field('product_image') ?>"/></p>
        <p><?php the_field('product_details') ?></p>
        <p><a href="<?php the_field('hyperlink_to_product_page') ?>">Product Web Page</a></p>
        <p><a href="<?php the_field('hyperlink_to_specifications') ?>">Product Sepcifications</a></p>   
    </div>
            <?php endif; endwhile;

  if($counter % $column_divide == 0) echo '<div class="row">';
  ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // so nothin' weird happens to other loops
        endif;

    }
}
?>

</div><!-- END .col-lg-12-->

            </div><!-- END .row -->
        </div>
        </div><!-- END .fl-content .col-lg-12-->
    </div><!-- END .row -->
</div><!-- END .fl-content-full .container -->
</div>


        <h1>hero banner - using beaver themer</h1>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).